# Return true if 2 strings are identical before special character

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like the following IF statement to return TRUE in both cases:

```
w = 'bask*'
l = ['basket','bask']

for x in l:    
    if w == x:
        do stuff
```

Can this be done with regex or some function I am not aware of?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that the two strings are equal before an index you know beforehand you can use the following.

```
w = 'bask'
l = ['basket','bask']

for x in l:
    if x[:len(w)] == w:  
        do stuff
```

**EDIT:** If all you care about is the presence of a substring rather than it's position as well, I'd recommend using the `in` operator. It would hold true in the sample set you provided.